# Is it safe to quit kernel_task?

Tags: macos, kernel, applications

I recently quit kernel_task because it was taking a lot of cpu time, when I was about to force quit it it says you will be logged out but I did not care but then after I force quit it I thought does it disrupt the system?

PS. Is quitting the kernel_task same as logging out?

Comment: don't do that. Kernel Task is the core of the os and without it you don't have a usable operating system.

Comment: And yes totally agree, but I had done it twice or thrice but I had encountered not problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Killing `kernel_task` is "killing" your entire system.

It's not the same as logging out; it's asking you to log out because everything will be going down.

From [What Is kernel_task, and Why Is It Running on My Mac?](https://www.howtogeek.com/310293/WHAT-IS-KERNEL_TASK-AND-WHY-IS-IT-RUNNING-ON-MY-MAC/)

> A “kernel,” if you didn’t know, is at the core of any operating
>   system, sitting between your CPU, memory, and other hardware and the
>   software that you run. When your turn on your Mac, the kernel is the
>   first thing that starts, and basically everything you do on your
>   computer flows through the kernel at some point. Activity Monitor puts
>   all of this varied activity under one banner: kernel_task.

Comment: So should I worry about any software damage? And does reinstall of OS fix it.Because after I force quit kernel_task I decided to reinstall OS. PS. I did a reinstall because in my internet speed it only takes 6 minutes.

Comment: Realistically, the only damage would be to open files.  You don't need to resinstall macOS after you do something; there's no point in doing so unless there's a bonafide reason.

Comment: Can't agree that `kernel_task` is the "entire system". My understanding is it's a process that protects the CPU from overheating by putting fake load on it until it's back to normal. In any case, force quitting is probably not a good idea either. What is `kernel_task`? From Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207359

Comment: @DavidJames - Re-read the support document you linked to.  It doesn't say, "its function is," but instead is says "*one of the functions*" meaning there is more to `kernel_task` than implementing dummy loads to thermally throttle a CPU.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification.